# Apacite, delete comma between Author/year, add colon between year and page

Tags: apa-style

I'm working for the first time with Apa in LaTeX (`\usepackage{apacite}`) and I'm having some trouble. When I use the command `\cite[202]{Haegeman:1997}` I get: `(McCloskey, 1997, 202)` which is fine, but my professor wants this output: `(McCloskey 1997: 202)`. Do you have any idea, how I can delete the common between  Author/year AND add colon between year and page?

Thank you in advance.

Carolina.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and, after a long research, I solved like this:

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage {apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand{\BBAY}{, }%% punctuation between authors and year
\renewcommand{\BBN}{: }%% punctuation between year and page number
\renewcommand{\BBYY}{, }%% punctuation between multiple years
}
```

You can change the colon between year and page number.

In LaTex:

```
\cite[138]{leeman1997}
```

The result: 
(Lehmann, 1997: 138)

Comment: I just got the error "! LaTeX Error: Command \BBAY undefined."